# readmodel for available data and selected data

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs

I'm trying to follow DDD and CQRS principles in the project I'm currently working on.
I'm now struggling with a design decision.
Let's say I have a page with a list of topics a users can subscribe to. The users also sees what topics he has subscribed to.
How do I retrieve the data? Do I query the topics and marked topics separately.

e.g.

- GetTopics
- GetMarkedTopicsForUser

and then in the view I do the magic of combining the 2 so that the users sees his subscriptions. 
Or do I make 1 model that contains all topics and already mark the topics the user have subscribed to

e.g.

- GetTopicOverviewForUser

Comment: a few questions: what's the max number of topics your system can have? what's the max number of topics a user can subscribe to? answers to this will impact your decisions on modelling.

Comment: The max number of topics would be 50. And the users can select all of the 50 topics if he wants.

Comment: As always, the answer is it depends... mostly on if they're only used together or can be used separately and how often they called?

Comment: I'd also note that CQRS is about the separation of the two main activities (Commands - changing state & Queries - retrieving state) - these are different models rather than implementation details.  If you're taking about EventSourcing that would be a different topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I have a page with a list of topics a users can subscribe to. The users also sees what topics he has subscribed to. How do I retrieve the data?

There is various ways to do this but I would create two [read models](https://cqrs.nu/Faq/read-sides):

- AllTopics: list of all topics
- UserWithTopics: to see what topics a user have subscribed to.

When constructing your page, you can then use both data to see what topics users can subscribe in that page, and probably unsubscribe. As you have at most 50 topics on both ends, performance for page construction shouldn’t be an issue.

Comment: I agree, otherwise, each user will get a huge read model with all the topics they haven't subscribed to, which will always need to be updated as soon as new topics appear, for no particular reason.

Answer (score 0):

This really comes down to a design decision - what are you going to show the users?

1. List of all topics and a list of current subscription
2. All Topics and if the user has a subscrition.

If 1, you want a results view...

```cs
var resultView = new TwoResultViews(avaiableTopics, subscriptionTopics);
```

returns

```
"res": {
  "availableTopics": 
  [
    {
       "topic": "topic1",
    }
  ],
  "subscribedTopics": 
  [
    {
       "topic": "anotherTopic"
    }
  ]
}
```

or if 2

```cs
var resultView = new SingleResultView(availableTopics, susbcrtiptionTopics);
```

returns

```
  [
    {
       "topic": "topic1",
       "subscribed": true
    }
  ],
```

Either way, you one want 1 call to the API, unless there are obvious (and accountable - aka performance) reasons to optimise it.

Comment: Ps. You can optimise option 2, to store the topic and the subscription state, but that comes with other trade offs.